# hibernate hql joins hashset question

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have three tables

users, survey, surveyreponses

I used hibernettool to generate the objects/mapping/xml etc

in the **survey** object there is a "set" of **surveyresponses**

private Set surveyresponses= new HashSet(0); <-- this is generated code inside survey class

I am running the query

```
select u.id, s from users u, survey s
where u.id = s.id
```

but my surveyresponses "set" is empty.
How do I add all those surveyresponses into the set in **survey**?
assuming I have the reference to survey id from surveyresponses

kinda new to hibernate =)
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thats because when you are doing HQL you will get a List that has the objects from your query in it, but it won't populate properties in your objects.  What you need to do is specify the set of survey responses in your survey's configuration like so:.

```
<set name="surveyresponses" inverse="true" lazy="true"  cascade="all-delete-orphan">                    
    <key>
        <column name="id" precision="10" scale="0" not-null="true" />
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="surveyresponse" />
</set>
```

Now whenever the survey is loaded Hibernate will populate your set.

Comment: I have something like that, the hibernettools generated. I think the problem is with my query?

Comment: can you post your config files and pojos as well?